# Hibernate Query Collection which also has a mapped entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Job Entity

```
 @ManyToMany
 @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
 @JoinTable(name="JOB_ACTIVITES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="jobId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="an"))
 private Collection<Activity> activities;
```

Activity Entity

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "dwgNo", referencedColumnName = "dwgNo"), @JoinColumn(name = "rev", referencedColumnName = "rev") })
private Drawing drawing;
```

Query

```
public List<Activity> getActivitiesByJobId(Long jobId) {
    String criteria = "SELECT jb.activities FROM Job jb WHERE jb.jobId=:jobId";
    List<Activity> activities = em.createQuery(criteria).setParameter("jobId", Long.valueOf(jobId)).getResultList();
    return activities;
}
```

Error

javax.el.ELException: /job.xhtml value="#{activity.drawing.dwgNo}": org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I understand the error, But I don't know how to modify my query to join the `Drawing` entity.

Something like

```
SELECT jb.activities FROM Job jb LEFT JOIN FETCH Drawing ON
ACTIVITY.dwgNo=Drawing.drwNo WHERE jb.jobId=:jobId";
```

but that syntax is more like native SQL.  How do you specify the path on a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate already knowws, thanks to the mapping of the associations, how they are mapped and linked together. So it doesn't need any `ON` clause.
You can assign an alias to every joined association in order to further join or express criterias:

```
select activity from Job job 
inner join job.activities activity
left join fetch activity.drawing
where job.jobId = :jobId
```

Comment: Path not found when I added "left join fetch activity.drawing". Closer inspection you have "Select Activity" whereas I am querying a collection of Activities.  Activities is a collection of the Job Entity.  Drawing is mapped entity of the Activity Entity.  Am I missing something that you are saying?

Comment: You want all the activities, with their drawing, of a given job, if I understood correctly. That's what the above query does. activity is the alias I gave to the job.activities join. It's valid JPQL, unless your entities are not as you told in your question. Note that I **don't** have "Select Activity". I have "select activity". Case matters.

Comment: Yes, Ah OK, I see . About to leave work will test tomorrow. Thanks